# Скрипт не работает на хостинге

Tags: python, pythonanywhere

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вообщем написал скрипт для беседы ВК, который присылает расписание по команде. Если запускать скрипт на компе, то всё отлично работает, на хостинге же ошибка, показанная на фото

```
def send_schedule(req_date):

    url = 'http://oreluniver.ru/schedule//7980///1630281600367/printschedule'
    bardak = requests.get(url)
    timetable = json.loads(bardak.text)
    print(bardak.text)
    title_subject = []
    type_lesson = []
    global number_lesson
    number_lesson = []
    date_lesson = []
    korpus = []
    number_room = []
    surname = []
    name = []
    global second_name
    second_name = []
    global time_lesson
    time_lesson = ['','8:30 - 10:00','10:10 - 11:40','12:00 - 13:30','13:40 - 15:10','15:20 - 16:50','17:00 - 18:30','18:40 - 20:10','20:15 - 21:45']
    send_msg = ''
    
    for i in timetable:
        if i == 'Authorization':
            break
        title_subject.append(timetable[i]['TitleSubject'])
        type_lesson.append(timetable[i]['TypeLesson'])
        number_lesson.append(timetable[i]['NumberLesson'])
        date_lesson.append(timetable[i]['DateLesson'])
        korpus.append(timetable[i]['Korpus'])
        number_room.append(timetable[i]['NumberRoom'])
        surname.append(timetable[i]['Family'])
        name.append(timetable[i]['Name'])
        second_name.append(timetable[i]['SecondName'])
        
    for i in range(len(date_lesson)):
        
        if date_lesson[i][-5:] == req_date:
            gender = second_name[i][-1]
            send_msg += '\n&#128214;'+title_subject[i]+', '+type_lesson[i]+'.\n'+'&#9200;'+time_lesson[number_lesson[i]]+'\n'+gender_detector(gender)+surname[i]+' '+name[i]+' '+second_name[i]+'\n'+'&#128682;'+korpus[i]+'-'+number_room[i]+'\n_____________________\n'
    return send_msg+'вот бы мне милого мальчика который напишет ночью: слышь, я те хостинг нашёл&#128157;'
```

Comment: Поставьте `print(bardak.text)` до `timetable = json.loads(bardak.text)` и посмотрите что там приходит

Comment: Попробуйте напечатать `print(bardak.text)` **до** загрузки `json` из него.

Comment: @insolor Синхронно ))

Answer (score 1):

При отправке запроса на указанный в вопросе адрес с бесплатного аккаунта pythonanywhere в ответе приходит такой результат:

```
>>> import requests
>>> result = requests.get('http://oreluniver.ru/schedule//7980///1630281600367/printschedule')
>>> print(result.text)
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
     Access Denied
  </HEAD>
<BODY>

<h1>Access Denied</h1>

<p>
Access to arbitrary websites is not available from free accounts;
you can only access sites that are on our
<a href="http://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist">whitelist</a>.
If you want to suggest something to add to our whitelist
drop us a line at support@pythonanywhere.com.  It will have
to have an official public API.
</p>


<p>
Alternatively, you can sign up for a paid account at
<a href="http://www.pythonanywhere.com/account/">http://www.pythonanywhere.com/account/</a>
</p>
<p>
If you have already got a paid account and you're still getting this messge,
you may need to reload your web app (from the "Web" tab) or restart
your consoles.  If that doesn't help, drop us a line at support@pythonanywhere.com.
</p>

</BODY>
```

Общий смысл этого текста в том, что с бесплатного аккаунта pythonanywhere нельзя получить доступ к произвольному сайту, а только к сайтам из ["белого" списка](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist/).

Решение — оплатить минимальную платную подписку pythonanywhere (5$ за месяц, см. https://www.pythonanywhere.com/pricing/), либо искать другой бесплатный хостинг без подобных ограничений. Либо найти где-то одноплатный компьютер типа raspberry pi, хоститься на нем.